# UI thread vs. BackGroundWorker thread

Tags: wpf, backgroundworker, dispatcher

Im reading a WPF book and I see this code:

```
    private void bgw1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int percenti;
        percenti = e.ProgressPercentage;
        progressBar1.Value = percenti;
    }
```

The question is simple.
if

ProgressBar belongs to UI Thread and 
BackGroundWorker works with a Background Thread

Why are there no errors (like: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.)?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why are there no errors (like: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.)?

This is one of the main advantages to using `BackgroundWorker`.  The BackgroundWorker component automatically marshals calls for progress and completion back to the synchronization context (thread) that starts the job.

In this case, that means that the event handlers for `ProgressChanged` (and the completion event) happen on the WPF UI thread.

Answer (score 2):

The `BackgroundWorker` handles the thread context switch for you. The event `BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged` will be raised on the UI-Thread and hence your callback `bgw1_ProgressChanged` will be called in the context of the UI-Thread.

This was the main purpose for the `BackgroundWorker`'s existence: To make async work easy and straight forward in conjunction with a UI.

`BackgroundWorker` exists since .NET 1.0. Now that we live in 2012, we have the [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) class and the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) and soon the c# `async` keyword as general means for everything async, wich makes the `BackgroundWorker` kind of obsolete or at least old school.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you cannot make changes in the Do_work method of the background worker.
progress_changed event keeps updating what is happening in the other thread.

Bes to clear your concept through this link-->
[https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners][1]